# Laravel Insert into Pivot Table

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to write data to the pivot table but i get 
***"Call to a member function guests() on null"***

this is my code where am i going wrong?

I have tried this and i'm confused on whats wrong

**Event Model**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model
{

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'events';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['headline', 'description', 'address', 'zip', 'longitude', 'latitude',
        'position', 'country_id', 'cat_id', 'start_date', 'end_date'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    /**
     * The products that belong to the shop.
     */
    public function guests()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Guest', 'event_guest', 'guest_id', 'event_id');
    }
}
```

**Guest Model**

```
     <?php

namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Guest extends Model
{

 protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'];
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Event', 'event_guest', 'event_id', 'guest_id');
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
 //RSVP events
public function rsvpCheck()
{
    $check = Guest::find(5);
    //$guestCheck = Event::where('id',5)->first();

    $check->events()->attach(2);

    return $check->events;
}
```

Comment: where are you callig `guest` method ?

Comment: in the events model ` public function guests()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Guest', 'event_guest', 'guest_id', 'event_id');
    }`

Comment: That is where you define it, but where do you call it

Comment: no.. not defining .. calling .. where ?

Comment: since your error says calling `guest()` on null, but I can't find any call to `guest` method in your code :(

Comment: I'm sorry, i misread, its called in the controller  $check->events()->attach(2);

Comment: if I'm not wrong .. you are calling `events` and not `guests` . right ?

Comment: are you sure that the code you posted is responsible for above error ?

Comment: Yes its i run the rsvpCheck () AND I GET THAT

Comment: ok.. If you check the error stack you would get the line number for error ? could you please check that ?

Comment: also.. try changing `Guest::find` with `Guest::findOrFail` , next your return statement.., is it supposed to be `$check->events()` ?

Comment: alright i changed it and i get an sql error

Comment: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`eventrsvp`.`event_guest`, CONSTRAINT `event_guest_event_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `event_guest` (`event_id`, `guest_id`) values (1, 2))

Comment: is there an event with id 2 ?

Comment: there error says that its not able to find event with id 2

Comment: just realise that you have defined the relationships wrong...

Comment: replace your relationship methods with one given in @mike's answer

Comment: it returns null

Comment: i don't understand, please give me an example

Answer (score 1):

Change your relationship methods as suggested by @Mike.

Change your `guests()` method in Event Model as below:

```
public function guests()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Guest');
    }
```

Change your `events()` method in Guest Model as below:

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Event');
}
```

Now, to insert data into pivot table you have two cases:
**1) No pivot data**

```
public function rsvpCheck()
{
    $check = Guest::findOrFail(5);
    $check->events()->attach(2);
    return $check->events();
}
```

**2) Extra data needs to be inserted in pivot table**

```
public function rsvpCheck()
{
    $data = ['attribute'=>'value'];//replace this with the data you want to insert 
    $check = Guest::findOrFail(5);
    $check->events()->attach(2,$data);
    return $check->events();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way. Add this below your create_events_migration

```
   Schema::create('event_guest', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->integer('event_id')->unsigned()->index();
       $table->foreign('event_id')->references('id')->on('events');
       $table->integer('guest_id')->unsigned()->index();
       $table->foreign('guest_id')->references('id')->on('guests');
    });
```

In your **Event** model use this relationship

```
public function guests()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Guest::class); // include at the top:  use App\Models\Guest;
    }
```

In your **Guest** model

```
public function events()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class); // include at the top:  use App\Models\Event;
        }
```

Add some dummy data in your database ( relations betwen events and guests) and paste this code in your routes

```
Route::get('/testguest', function(){

            $guest= Guest::first();
            dd($company->events);

        });
```

and viceversa

Route::get('/testevents', function(){

```
            $event= Event::first();
            dd($event->guests);

        });
```

Let me know if you got it working so far and got your dummy data

Comment: i'm not trying to view, i'm trying to save to database in the pivot table

Comment: Are the relationships working? Just trying to debug it

Comment: i have this public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('event_guest', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('event_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('event_id')->references('id')->on('events')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('guest_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('guest_id')->references('id')->on('guests')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->primary(['event_id', 'guest_id']);
        });
    }

Comment: It returns Collection {#375 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: Did you add some values in `event_guest ` table ?

Comment: my question still stands, how do i insert into pivot table

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships